# why Libraries window in win7 32 bit is automatically opened after uninstalling an application designed by Installshield 2010?

Tags: windows-7, installation, installshield-2010

An application setup is designed by Installshield 2010. After uninstalling the application, Libraries window in win7 32 bit is automatically opened. Is there anyone who has the same experience, and what is the way to solve this problem?